# Now that userscripts.org is essentially dead, is any action required for link-only answers that referenced the site?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

It seems like [userscripts.org](https://userscripts.org) is dead (or at least, down for the last month with no word of coming back), and all the link-only answers that referenced it are now completely useless.  Since link-only answers are not really encouraged in the first place, is there any sort of bulk action needed to remove these answers from the site?  Doesn't really seem like there's any way to salvage them.

Examples: [One](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18962749/537031) [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3640810/537031) [Three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5355457/537031)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22userscripts.org%22

Comment: Just redirect them to http://userscripts.org:8080/ :P

Comment: @slhck Oh interesting... I guess that is an option, too.

Comment: I have no idea why they'd take down their web server on port 80 but keep it running there. Either way it's probably not a long-term solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [404 link checker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130398/does-stack-exchange-crawl-websites) that runs; I believe it either flags or removes posts with dead links.

If you want to be proactive; you can always write an SEDE query and start flagging those posts that have the following characteristics:

- only relevant information to the question is contained in a link
- That links is part of a dead domain (in this case, userscripts)

If the answer has relevant information that helps to answer the question outide of that script, then flagging is not necessary; instead leave a comment suggesting the OP update to a URL that works, or (even better), posts the information into the answer.

Comment: That actually still runs? Didn't know that. I thought they ditched that whole project along with the "Broken Links" review queue.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: I'm pretty sure that project died. I thought waffles was working on a view to expose the broken links before he left. Shame it never got finished.